# is the loadJSONArray() going to wreck my code's efficiency?

Tags: json, processing

I am using processing3.0.2 to create a UI for a piece of processing equipment. As it operates I want it to store its data locally in a JSON file. However, I am worried that as this file grows, the UI will bog down the system. I just want it to append another entry to the JSON array. There are no gets called.

The JSON file will start small, but will likely be a few hundred MBs quickly. So obviously reading this file every 15 min to write a new line is not very efficient. I have no idea how java works at all. So this is likely a very noob question, but is the loadJSONArray() the memory intensive step? If so, is there some way I can just append another line a text to the file without loading it? Or will using the append command add another entry in the array without actually reading any of the file.

Comment: I can not answer your question, and this might be a horrible suggestion but what about a buffer JSON object that you write to very quickly but keep it small, then periodically copy its data to a master JSON array??

Comment: short answer: yes. If you want a data store, use a data store that you store/retrieve to and from via a URL and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a lot of broad questions, and the only way to answer them is to actually code something and test it out. You should do that before you read the rest of my answer.

If you're worried about doing something that takes a long time, you should consider using a **Thread** so your main program can continue executing code. Consider this sketch:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void mousePressed(){
 delay(5000); 
}

void draw(){ 
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
}
```

This code calls the `delay()` function, which blocks the main thread, which causes your program to stop responding. This is exactly like loading or saving a large file.

However, you can make sure your program is responsive by using another Thread to handle the long task:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void mousePressed(){

  new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      println("Waiting.");
      delay(5000); 
      println("Done waiting.");
    }
  }.start();

}

void draw(){ 
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
}
```

Threading can become very complicated, but if you're asking how to make sure your program is responsive even though you might have to load large files, then they are certainly one approach worth investigating.

If you're asking if it's possible to append to a file, then the answer is yes. Just use a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) and pass in `true` to its constructor to tell it to append to the file:

```
PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("YourFileName.txt", true)));
out.println("Your JSON goes here");
out.close();
```

Both of these approaches are Java-only, and you won't be able to deploy as Processing.js if you go with them. They're also a little more hands-on than most Processing sketches require, so like I said at the beginning: make sure you actually have a problem before you try to solve it.